# Get length of multibyte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: c, utf-8

I am parsing some UTF-8 text but am only interested in characters in the ASCII range, i.e., I can just skip multibyte sequences.

I can easily detect the beginning of a sequence because the sign bit is set, so the `char` value is < 0.  But how can I tell how many bytes are in the sequence so I can skip over it?

I do not need to perform any validation, i.e., I can assume the input is valid UTF-8.

Comment: Remember that `char` can be implemented as either signed or unsigned, depending on your compiler.  If a char `ch` has the high bit set, it might mean `ch < 0` or it might mean `ch >= 128`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just strip out all bytes which are no valid ascii, don't try to get cute and interpret bytes >127 at all. This works as long as you don't have any combining sequences with base character in ascii range. For those you would need to interpret the codepoints themselves.

Comment: That is not a very good idea. You may, in this case, include characters that are part of UTF-8 sequence

Comment: @Yossarian: Please give an example. UTF-8 expressly makes your scenario impossible AFAIK.

Comment: @Yossarian All UTF-8 sequences that consists of more than 1 byte (2,3,4) consists _only_ of bytes that have the MSBit set.

Comment: @chux: Use NFD or characters with multiple diacritics, and yes it does. Though those are seldom used in real life.

Comment: @Deduplicator  I see your concern with [Unicode equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).  If a 'é' was composed of Unicode codepoint x00e9 or an 'e' (x0065) and '◌́ '  (x0301).   So if we only are concerned about non-combined codepoints, your solution works fine.  I suspect it also mets OP's goal.  Still like your solution the best.

Comment: @goldilocks & Yossarian, need to amend my assertion about `UTF-8 sequences` in light of UTF-8 sequences [Unicode equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).  An "un-combined" UTF-8 sequences that consists of more than 1 byte (2,3,4) consists only of bytes that have the MSBit set.

Answer (score 5):

Although Deduplicator's answer is more appropriate to the specific purpose of skipping over multibyte sequences, if there is a need to get the length of each such character, pass the first byte to this function:

```
int getUTF8SequenceLength (unsigned char firstPoint) {
    firstPoint >>= 4;
    firstPoint &= 7;
    if (firstPoint == 4) return 2;
    return firstPoint - 3;
}
```

This returns *the total length* of the sequence, including the first byte.      I'm using an unsigned char value as the `firstPoint` parameter here for clarity, but note this function will work exactly the same way if the parameter is a signed char.

To explain:

- UTF-8 uses bits 5, 6, and 7 in the first byte of a sequence to indicate the remaining length.  If all three are set, the sequence is 3 additional bytes.  If only the first of these *from the left* (the 7th bit) is set, the sequence is 1 additional byte.  If the first two from the left are set, the sequence is 2 additional bytes. Hence, we want to examine these three bits (the value here is just an example):

  ```
   11110111
    ^^^
  ```
- The value is shifted down by 4 then AND'd with 7.  This leaves only the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd bits *from the right* as the only possible ones set.  The value of these bits are 1, 2, and 4 respectively.

  ```
  00000111
       ^^^
  ```
- If the value is now 4, we know only the first bit from the left (of the three we are considering) is set and can return 2.
- After this, the value is either 7, meaning all three bits are set, so the sequence is 4 bytes in total, or 6, meaning the first two from the left are set so the sequence is 3 bytes in total.

This covers the range of valid Unicode characters expressed in UTF-8.